# after ajax call my document ready script not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide one `div` after an AJAX but it's not working. My script works before the AJAX call but after afterwards the first script does not work. How can I hide my `div`?

```
$(function () {
    $("div.product-spec-filter div.filter-content").hide(); // this line not work after ajax call       

});
```

Comment: `.live()` is removed from the latest jquery, now `.on()` is the preferred way.

Comment: write one call back function on the success of ajax call and then move your code there

Comment: tiger sir i done this but its not work

Comment: thank for sujjectin jai but my live() script is workin fine

Comment: What @Jai meant is when you update your library in the future to a more recent jQuery version, this function will break due to the fact that the functionality `live` has been removed. `on` will always work. In your version and in future version. You should change it.

Comment: k implement it now but still problem occure. and jain means persion who give me answare in my above comment check it.

Comment: Can you post the html part.

Answer (score 0):

When implemented like this, it should work:

```
    //bogus ajax call just to give an example of the done functionality
    $.ajax({

      method: "POST",

      url: "some.php",

      data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }

    })

      .done(function( msg ) {

        //this will fire when the ajax request returns success.
        hideDiv();

      });



    function hideDiv() {
        $("div.product-spec-filter div.filter-content").hide(); // this line not work after ajax call
        //$("div.product-spec-filter div.filter-title").click(function () {
        $("div.product-spec-filter div.filter-title").on("click", function () {
            $("div.category-listbox-title").next("div.listbox").slideToggle("slow");
            $(this).next("div.filter-content").slideToggle("slow");
        });

        //$("div.block-category-navigation div.category-listbox-title").click(function () {
        $("div.block-category-navigation div.category-listbox-title").on("click", function () {
            $("div.product-spec-filter").find("div.filter-content").slideToggle("slow");
            $(this).next("div.listbox").slideToggle("slow");
        });

    }
```

Comment: on successs and done event my alert work but div is not hide in this success event.

Comment: thanks for answare Mouser but still issue not solve.

Comment: my selector is working fine beause i try to run in my console of browser after ajax call is complete that time from browser's console i run this first script line to hide dive is working fine but if i put this  code in my sucess event its not working;

Comment: Still, to help you further post the HTML please.